# File.exists returning false

Tags: android, file

I am trying to access a file twice in my program.

First I am reading from the file, which runs fine.

The second time, I am trying to delete the same file from which I read.

Strangely the second time no records are present in the file. In fact when I try to run the command `file.exists` it returns false. **Why is this happening?**

Following is my code:

```
public class ControlLights extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RoomListAdapter adapter;
    private List<ROOM> mRoomList;

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup,menu);
    }

    public void filedel(int pos) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File filemain = new File("roomdata.txt");
        try {
            File temp = File.createTempFile("file",".txt",filemain.getParentFile());
            String charset = "UTF-8";
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(temp), charset));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));
            int p=0;
            for(String line; (line=reader.readLine())!=null;) {
                if(p == pos) {
                    line = line.replace(line,"");
                    writer.println(line);
                }
                writer.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
            filemain.delete();
            temp.renameTo(filemain);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Edit:
                return true;

            case R.id.Delete:
                filedel(info.position);
                mRoomList.remove(info.position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void loadrooms() {

        int block = 1024;

        try {
            boolean exists = (new File("roomdata.txt").exists());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(exists), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("roomdata.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            char[] data = new char[block];
            String roomdata = "";
            int size;
            try {
                while ((size = isr.read(data)) > 0) {
                    String read_data = String.copyValueOf(data, 0, size);
                    roomdata += read_data;
                    data = new char[block];
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String[] room_display = roomdata.split("\n");
            String[] tempstring;
            ListView lsv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Room_list);
            mRoomList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int b = 0; b < room_display.length; b++) {
                tempstring = room_display[b].split(":");
                mRoomList.add(new ROOM(tempstring[0], tempstring[1], tempstring[2], tempstring[3], tempstring[4], tempstring[5], tempstring[6], tempstring[7], tempstring[8], tempstring[9]));
            }

            adapter = new RoomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mRoomList);
            lsv.setAdapter(adapter);
            registerForContextMenu(lsv);


            int count = mRoomList.size();
            final ArrayList<Integer> disabledpos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int q = 0; q < count; q++) {
                ROOM temp_room1 = mRoomList.get(q);
                String IP = temp_room1.getRoom_IP_Address();
                String online = null;
                ConnectionTest CT = new ConnectionTest();
                try {
                    online = CT.execute(IP, "a", "b").get();
                    Boolean b1 = Boolean.valueOf(online);

                    if (!b1) {
                        disabledpos.add(q);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            try {
                isr.reset();
                isr.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (new File("roomdata.txt").delete()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Not deleted
            }

            lsv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    int temp_position = position;
                    Intent p = new Intent(ControlLights.this, Electrical_equipment_list.class);
                    if (!(disabledpos.contains(position))) {
                        ROOM temp_room = mRoomList.get(temp_position);
                        p.putExtra("EE1", temp_room.getEE1());
                        p.putExtra("EE2", temp_room.getEE2());
                        p.putExtra("EE3", temp_room.getEE3());
                        p.putExtra("EE4", temp_room.getEE4());
                        p.putExtra("EE5", temp_room.getEE5());
                        p.putExtra("EE6", temp_room.getEE6());
                        p.putExtra("EE7", temp_room.getEE7());
                        p.putExtra("EE8", temp_room.getEE8());
                        p.putExtra("IPaddress", temp_room.getRoom_IP_Address());
                        startActivity(p);
                    }
                }
            });   

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control_lights);
        loadrooms();
    }

    public class ConnectionTest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Boolean online;
            String tempstring = null;
            try {
                InetAddress roomaddress = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
                online = roomaddress.isReachable(100);
                tempstring = String.valueOf(online);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return tempstring;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep your `File` as a class' member, since it is an essential component of what the class does
2. Move your inner logic and file reference initialization to `onStart()`

   public class ControlLights extends AppCompatActivity {
       private RoomListAdapter adapter;
       private List mRoomList;
       private File filemain;
       ...

   ```
   public void filedel(int pos) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       try {
           File temp = File.createTempFile("file",".txt", filemain.getParentFile());
           ...
       }
   }

   public void loadrooms() {
       int block = 1024;
       try {
           boolean exists = filemain.exists();
           ...
           if (filemain.delete()) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // Not deleted
           }
       } ...
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_control_lights);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       filemain = new File("roomdata.txt");
       loadrooms();
   }
   ```

   }

**Foot note**

I apologize for the horrible code format, but apparently they changed the parsing algorithm to a point where you have to manually type all the code again here instead of just being able to copy-paste it. Anyone being to edit it accordingly is welcome.

Comment: Thanks chisko.  I was finally able to delete the file using deletefile command.  My observation is that file created using file input stream cannot be deleted using file.delete command. Correct me if i am wrong. Looking forward to hear from you.